# Regex Python firstname lastname tag the keywords in json dump

Tags: python, json, regex

Python Regex : 
I have a json file and list of keywords.
I need to match the keywords in the json file dump. 
I have set of keywords : Data Filter Terms:

```
Candidate Names

Hillary Clinton

Bernie Sanders

Jeb Bush

Donald Trump

John Kasich

Marco Rubio

Scott Walker
```

I need to match these keywords in such a way that it should search for 
'Scott Walker' as well as 'Scott','Walker' independently too. 
and I need to tag these in the json dump. 
can anyone help me out in this?

I wrote a pseudocode for this :

```
import re

json_pages = open('/home/Desktop/arti.json','r')
filterd_pages = []
for page in json_pages:
   text = page['text']
   re.match('Hillary Clinton')
   if matches:
    page['matched_keyword'] = matches.group()
    filterd_pages.append(page)
dump_json(filterd_pages)



f = open('/home/soundarya/Documents/synapsifyone.json')
json_response = json.loads(f.read())
keywords = ['Hillary Clinton ', 'Bernie Sanders', 'Jeb Bush','Donald Trump','John Kasich','Marco Rubio','Scott Walker']
for k, v in json_response.iteritems():
    if k in keywords:
        print(v)
        break
```

How to tag the keywords in the JSON dump?

I have crawled so many datas , posts from nearly 30 urls using Diffbot tool and got json as the output file. from this json file i have to match the keywords (First Name , Last Name, First Name Last Name) and tag it at the end of each dict in the list or return the sentences which have the sentences that contain - 'hillary' , 'clinton' or 'Hillary Clinton.

Comment: Can you show some sample input and output?

Comment: It should search for particular keyword - firstname lastname and tag in the json dump.. for eg. hillary clinton - hillary or clinton - it should tag at the end of each dictionary --> these are the tagged words (Tags: Hillary, Clinton, Hillary Clinton) like that.

Comment: What do you mean you don't have sample input / output? Can you make some up? It's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: Soundary it is important to have a clear view of the question, you should provide a sample input/output so that people here at SO can help you about. Its not clear what you actually need.

Comment: I have crawled so many datas , posts from nearly 30 urls using Diffbot tool and got json as the output file. from this json file i have to match the keywords (First Name , Last Name, First Name Last Name) and tag it at the end of each dict in the list or return the sentences which have the sentences that contain - 'hillary' , 'clinton' or 'Hillary Clinton'

Comment: Write it in the question not in the comment section.

Comment: @SoundaryaThiagarajan, remember that we know nothing about what you're doing except what you tell us. It's really helpful to have sample input and output; it doesn't have to be long, just demonstrate what you want.

Comment: I have the json - as a list of dictionaries. in this each dict is a post. and i need to find the matches of these keywords and tag at the end of each dict that these are the occurences -- in the dict.

Comment: @SoundaryaThiagarajan, you might have an answer by now if you had just posted some sample input / output when I first asked :). It does not have to be large or include irrelevant data; it just has to show us exactly what you want to do.

Comment: can you help me writing a regex for searching in the json - for the keywords - ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of regular expressions, one for each term. The idea is to construct a regular expression that matches either the whole term or any word in it.

```
term_regexes = []
term_tags = []

for term in term_file:
    term_matchers = [term] + term.split()
    term_regexes.append('|'.join(term_matchers))
    term_tags.append(term)
```

We are creating a list to hold the regular expressions and another for holding the tags.

`term_file` contains each term. For each of them, we construct the regular expression that matches either the term or any of its parts. This corresponds to the union of the expressions matching each one of them, using the union ("or") regex operator ("`|`").  For instance, the expression "Hillary Clinton|Hillary|Clinton" would do the job for your example.

Finally, we iterate the list of dictionaries, search for a match of any of the terms and tag when found:

```
for d in dict_list:
    # Search each term.
    for term_regex, tag in zip(term_matchers, term_tags):
        if re.match(term_regex, d['text'], re.IGNORECASE):
            d['tag'] = tag
            break
```